# Can't get UILabel text shadow to be any color but gray

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

So I'm setting UILabel.shadowColor to a non-gray color, but the shadow always appears as opaque 50% gray (or so). For example, I tried setting the shadow to red and I still see gray. Has anyone else seen this? (This is the UILabel inside a custom nav bar back button)

Comment: voted down? why? (i'm new here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this same problem while trying to add a non-gray drop shadow to a `UIButton`'s `titleLabel`. The solution appears to be to set the properties of the button's `layer` instead:

```
button.titleLabel.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
button.titleLabel.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
button.titleLabel.layer.shadowOpacity = 1;
button.titleLabel.layer.shadowRadius = 0;
```

`shadowOpacity` is necessary for the effect to appear at all, and `shadowRadius` has to be set explicitly since the default is 3.0 (very blurry).

This solution requires `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`.

Comment: man--seems obvious in hindsight. not working on this code anymore, but I believe you. Accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are not confusing backgroundColor with shadowColor?

Comment: yeah--pretty sure. since i tried red, I think that would have shown up right away. Thanks though.